# Boundary version of the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I was looking for a detailed version with proof of the following statement:
$$\int_{\partial D} (f\varphi  +X \cdot \operatorname{grad}\varphi ) \,\,\mathrm d a =0
~~~~\forall \varphi:D \to \mathbb R ~~~~~\Longrightarrow~~~~~ f=0,~X=0 ~~\text{on}~ \partial D .$$
Here $D$ is a three-dimensional domain.
It is some sort of boundary version of the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations with the derivatives of the test function.
A simple reference would be ok.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the regularity of $f$ and $X$? And is the first integral really over $\partial D$?

Comment: Thing is that I suspect something like this needs to hold under pretty reasonable assumptions. I was just looking for a formal statement with proof. In short, you choose the regularity ($C^2$?). Yes, the integral is on the boundary, which is the whole point.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, integration by parts gives us $\int_{\partial D} ( f\varphi  +X \cdot \operatorname{grad}\varphi ) = \int_{\partial D} (f - \operatorname{div}_{\partial D} X) \varphi$ (since $\partial D$ is a closed submanifold), so one would expect just $f - \operatorname{div}_{\partial D} X = 0$.

Comment: Yes, that is the standard procedure, but here $\operatorname{grad}\varphi$ is not a surface operator. It carries information from the interior of $D$...

Comment: You're right, I missed that. But then, the full $\operatorname{grad} \varphi$ is decomposed into the $\partial D$-part $\operatorname{grad}_{\partial D} \varphi$ (for which the previous comment applies) and the normal part $\partial_n \varphi \cdot \vec{n}$, which can be an arbitrary normal field (independently of $\varphi|_{\partial D}$). So I would then expect $f - \operatorname{div}_{\partial D} X = 0$ and $X \cdot \vec{n} = 0$, not more.

Comment: No curvature of the boundary shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\n}{\mathbf{n}}$
$\newcommand{\pl}{\partial}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\dv}{div}$
$\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$

For simplicity, let me assume that $D \subseteq \R^n$ is a bounded smooth domain, so that $\pl D$ is a closed submanifold. Let me also assume that $f \colon \pl D \to \R$ and $X \colon \pl D \to \R^n$ are smooth. Our assumption is that
$$
\int_{\pl D} f \vp + X \cdot \nabla \vp = 0 
\quad \text{for all smooth } \vp,
$$
where $\vp$ is defined on all of $\overline{D}$ (or even $\R^n$) and $\nabla \vp$ is the full gradient.

Let us denote by $\n$ the unit outer normal to $\pl D$ and decompose $X$ and $\nabla \vp$ into their tangent and normal parts:
$$
X = X^\top + X^\perp \cdot \n, 
\quad 
\nabla \vp = \nabla_{\pl D} \vp + \pl_\n \vp \cdot \n,
$$
so that $X \cdot \nabla \vp$ becomes
$$ 
X \cdot \nabla \vp 
= X^\top \cdot \nabla_{\pl D} \vp + X^\perp \cdot \pl_\n \vp.
$$
The first part can be integrated by parts over $\pl D$, yielding
$$
\int_{\pl D} X^\top \cdot \nabla_{\pl D} \vp 
= - \int_{\pl D} \dv_{\pl D} X^\top \cdot \vp.
$$
Our main assumption then translates to the statement that for each smooth $\vp$ we have
$$
0 = \int_{\pl D} f \vp + X \cdot \nabla \vp 
= \int_{\pl D} (f - \dv_{\pl D} X^\top) \cdot \vp + \int_{\pl D} X^\perp \cdot \pl_\n \vp.
$$
I claim that $\vp$ and $\pl_\n \vp$ can be chosen as arbitrary smooth functions on $\pl D$, so our starting assumption is equivalent to
$$
f = \dv_{\pl D} X^\top, \quad 
X^\perp = 0 
\quad \text{on } \pl D.
$$
To justify the claim, let us choose arbitrary smooth functions $a,b \colon \pl D \to \R$. The formula
$$
\vp(x+t\n) = a(x)+tb(x)
$$
gives us a well-defined function on a tubular neighborhood of $\pl D$, which can be extended elsewhere, if needed. Of course, $\vp = a$ and $\pl_\n \vp = b$ on $\pl D$.

---

**What about curvature?** The integration by parts formula $\int_{\pl D} X^\top \cdot \nabla_{\pl D} \vp = - \int_{\pl D} \dv_{\pl D} X^\top \cdot \vp$ is a consequence of  the formula $\int_{\pl D} \dv_{\pl D} V = 0$ valid for tangent fields $V$ on $\pl D$.
If in doubts, this can be further translated to an intrinsic formula (Gauss-Green, Stokes) for abstract manifolds, e.g. by translating fields and divergences into forms and differentials.

The mean curvature pops out when one applies $\dv_{\pl D} V$ (understood as $\operatorname{tr}(DV \circ (T_x \pl D)_\#)$) to a general (not tangent) vector field. The result is indeed
$$
\int_{\pl D} \dv_{\pl D} V = - \int_{\pl D} V \cdot \mathbf{h},
$$
where $\mathbf{h}$ is the mean curvature vector. See the definition of first variation [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05253) (sorry for unnecessary generality).

Comment: Got it. If with $\cdot$ you mean scalar product, then there are couple corrections to be made. Also, it'd be interesting to see how this extends to higher orders, i.e., starting from something like $\int_{\partial D} (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{B}:\nabla\mathbf{w})\,\mathrm d a = 0$...

Comment: Yes, by $\cdot$ I mean either scalar product (if both terms are vectors) or the usual product (if at least one of them is a scalar). What are the corrections?

Comment: I meant on that notation. Ok, I think this is solved, thanks!